# Combine neural network layer kernels into one kernel CUDA

Tags: c++, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, cuda

I am working on a CUDA implementation of a neural network and I'm wondering how the calculations within a fully connected layer can be optimized more.

My current CUDA kernel for a fully connected layer in a neural network consists of the following steps:

1. Set the output neuron accumulators (`input`) to 0
2. Multiply the output data from the previous layer (`in`) with the `weights` of the current layer and sum the result in the accumulator
3. Calculate the output of the current layer (`out`) by applying an activation function to the accumulated data

These are general steps in a single layer of neural network, but are currently (see below) implemented as separate kernels. For small output sizes (`outSizeX` equals 10 for example), the first and third step are relatively slow, especially combined with launching the three kernels.

Thus, my question is: how can I combine these three kernels into one kernel which performs all of the three above mentioned steps?

```cpp
// Step 1
__global__ void set_to_zero_cuda(float *__restrict__ input, int outSizeX)
{
  int i = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

  if (i >= outSizeX)
    return;

  input[i] = 0;
}

// Step 2
__global__ void activate_cuda_fc(const float *__restrict__ in, float *__restrict__ input, const float *__restrict__ weights,
                                 int totalInSize, int outSizeX, int weightSizeX)
{
  int x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  int y = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;

  int nx = blockDim.x * gridDim.x;
  int ny = blockDim.y * gridDim.y;

  for (int n = x; n < outSizeX; n += nx)
  {
    for (int i = y; i < totalInSize; i += ny)
    {
      atomicAdd(&input[n], in[i] * weights[i + n * weightSizeX]);
    }
  }
}

// Step 3
__global__ void perform_activation_function_cuda_fc(float *__restrict__ out, float *input,
                                                    int outSizeX)
{
  int i = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

  if (i >= outSizeX)
    return;

  out[i] = activator_function_cuda(input[i]);
}
```

For reference, the current profile looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> Thus, my question is: how can I combine these three kernels into one kernel which performs all of the three above mentioned steps?

Unless you are using a linear activation function, you can't "collapse" a sequence of fully connected layers like this.

Applying the weights and biases to the inputs of each layer is exactly the kind of trivially parallelizable linear algebra operation that are the bread and butter of GPUs. However, for that to work efficiently, you need to have all inputs of a layer ready before you launch it. Anything that precludes doing that operation in bulk will hurt performance immediately.

At the same time, since most activation functions introduce nonlinearity, they cannot be embedded directly into a linear algebra process, so you don't have much choice but to perform them separately.

However, there's still a lot of gains to be made in the code you posted. As I said, applying the weights and biases is the bread and butter of GPUs. In fact, it's effectively the exact same thing as transforming a vector by a matrix, but you are going about that in a rather roundabout way. Using a ready-made function M*V function such as [`cublasSgemv()`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublas-lt-t-gt-gemv) would most likely give you some immediate benefits.

**Addendum**:

If you *are* using a linear activation function, then you are effectively doing `y = A3 * L3 * A2 * L2 * A1 * L1 * x` where `Ln` is the matrix associated with a layer, and the activation function `An` are just scalars. You can premultiply all the `A`'s and `L`'s together ahead of time and treat it as one big matrix multiplication.